# Godot's Area2D not detecting collision immediately, sometimes

Tags: collision-detection, godot

I have a hotbar that sits at the top until the player gets close, then it moves to the bottom and vice versa. Area2D works great at the top, it reacts immediately at first touch, but the bottom I have to go a ways in before it reacts:
[HotbarTop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl5E3.png)
[HotbarBottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Te3.png)

Here's my code:

```
func _on_HotbarCollision_area_entered(area):
    if hotPosition == hotTopPosition:
        hotPosition = hotBottomPosition
        count = 0
    elif hotPosition == hotBottomPosition:
        hotPosition = hotTopPosition
        count = 0

    position = hotPosition
    print(area)
```

Any ideas where the problem might be?

As you can see, I've turned on Visible Collision Shapes and when it prints it shows that the Player is triggering it.
I've tried deleting and adding the nodes. Tried changing the signal to Area_Shape_Entered. I've tried changing the CollisionShape2D to a different shape. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If you change initial position of the bar to bottom instead of top, is the problem reversed? Also are you using Godot 3 or Godot 4?

Comment: Nothing changes when I set the initial position of the bar to the bottom of the screen. I am using Godot 3.
It seems to work fine when I set the display window to be 896 x 896 but it gets this problem when I have it set to 224  x 224